# SplashScreen Black and White Screen is Open while app is opening and SplashScreen Open Late How can i Fix this issue?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

**This is My SplashScreen Code**
**Here splashScreen Call how can i try to fix this and i change it from StatefulWidget to StatelessWidget**

```
import 'package:cms/Configs/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Splashscreen extends StatefulWidget
{
 @override
 _Splashscreen createState() => _Splashscreen();
}

class _Splashscreen extends State<Splashscreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return IsSplashOnlySolidColor == true
? Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
body: Center(
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      valueColor:
      AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
))
: Scaffold(
 backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
 body: Center(
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/images/logo.png',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
   )),
  );
 }
}
```

**This is my main.dart File Code**
**Splashscreen is Work as a Function in main.dart file it is open very late and black/white screen is show while app is opening How can i fix this issue**

```
void main() async {
if (Platform.isIOS) {
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(myBackgroundMessageHandlerIos);
}
if (DESIGN_TYPE == Themetype.messenger) {
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor:
    Color(0XFFFFFFFF), //or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
}
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
final WidgetsBinding binding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

binding.renderView.automaticSystemUiAdjustment = false;
runApp(OverlaySupport(child: CMSWrapper()));
}

class CMSWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
const CMSWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) {
_CMSWrapperState? state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_CMSWrapperState>();
state!.setLocale(newLocale);
}


@override
_CMSWrapperState createState() => _CMSWrapperState();
}
class _CMSWrapperState extends State<CMSWrapper> {
Locale? _locale;
 setLocale(Locale locale) {
setState(() {
  _locale = locale;
});
}
final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
@override
 void didChangeDependencies() {
getLocale().then((locale) {
  setState(() {
    this._locale = locale;
  });
});
super.didChangeDependencies();
} 
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final FirebaseGroupServices firebaseGroupServices = FirebaseGroupServices();
final FirebaseBroadcastServices firebaseBroadcastServices =
FirebaseBroadcastServices();
if (_locale == null) {
  return Container(
    child: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color?>(Colors.blue[800])),
    ),
  );
 } else {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(
            'ERROR OCCURED WHILE INITIALIZING FIREBASE',
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
              builder:
                  (context, AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return MultiProvider(
                    providers: [
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(
                          create: (_) => StatusProvider()),
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(
                          create: (_) => AvailableContactsProvider()),
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Observer()),
                      Provider(create: (_) => SeenProvider()),
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(
                          create: (_) => DownloadInfoprovider()),
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProvider()),
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(
                          create: (_) =>
                              FirestoreDataProviderCALLHISTORY()),
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(
                          create: (_) => CurrentChatPeer()),
                    ],
                    child: StreamProvider<List<BroadcastModel>>(
                      initialData: [],
                      create: (BuildContext context) =>
                          firebaseBroadcastServices.getBroadcastsList(
                              snapshot.data!.getString(Dbkeys.phone) ?? ''),
                      child: StreamProvider<List<GroupModel>>(
                        initialData: [],
                        create: (BuildContext context) =>
                            firebaseGroupServices.getGroupsList(
                                snapshot.data!.getString(Dbkeys.phone) ??
                                    ''),
                        child: MaterialApp(
                          builder: (BuildContext? context, Widget? widget) {
                            ErrorWidget.builder =
                                (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
                              return CustomError(
                                  errorDetails: errorDetails);
                            };

                            return widget!;
                          },
                          theme: ThemeData(
                              fontFamily: FONTFAMILY_NAME,
                              primaryColor: Cmsgreen,
                              primaryColorLight: Cmsgreen,
                              indicatorColor: CmsLightGreen),
                          title: Appname,

                          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

                          home: Homepage(
                            prefs: snapshot.data!,
                            currentUserNo:
                            snapshot.data!.getString(Dbkeys.phone),
                            isSecuritySetupDone: snapshot.data!.getString(
                                Dbkeys.isSecuritySetupDone) ==
                                null
                                ? false
                                : ((snapshot.data!
                                .getString(Dbkeys.phone) ==
                                null)
                                ? false
                                : (snapshot.data!.getString(Dbkeys
                                .isSecuritySetupDone) ==
                                snapshot.data!
                                    .getString(Dbkeys.phone))
                                ? true
                                : false),
                          ),

                          // ignore: todo
                          //TODO:---- All localizations settings----
                          locale: _locale,
                          supportedLocales: [
                            Locale('en','US'),
                            Locale('hi','IN'),
                            Locale('pa','IN'),
                            Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'en')
                          ],
                          localizationsDelegates: [
                            DemoLocalization.delegate,
                            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                          ],
                          localeResolutionCallback:(locale, supportedLocales)
                          {
                            for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
                              if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale!.languageCode &&
                                  supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
                                return supportedLocale;
                              }
                            }
                            return supportedLocales.first;
                          },
                          //--- All localizations settings ended here----
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return MultiProvider(
                  providers: [
                    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProvider()),
                  ],
                  child: MaterialApp(
                      theme: ThemeData(
                          fontFamily: FONTFAMILY_NAME,
                          primaryColor: Cmsgreen,
                          primaryColorLight: Cmsgreen,
                          indicatorColor: CmsLightGreen),
                      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                      home: Splashscreen()),
                );
              });
        }
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Splashscreen(),
        );
      });
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before your Splashscreen widget is shown, Flutter needs some time loading the Framework. While loading, an Operating System native splash screen is shown. This splash screen has to be configured differently for every OS. See: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

After the Framework is finished loading, your Splashscreen widget will be shown.